# Can't type anything on Visual Studio Code's C# output

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, input

so i was trying to run a really basic C# program on vscode, here's the code:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Name;
            Console.Write("Input your username:\n");    
            Console.Write("u/");
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("\nSo your username is u/" + Name);
        }
    }
}
```

And naturally, it outputs:

> Input your username:

> u/

Except that i can't type anything next to the "u/", not even below.
it doesn't even freeze, popup an error or something like that, it just shows nothing.

and the same problem happens with C and C++. any tip?

Comment: This works fine for me.
`string Name = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: do you modified some kind of setting? i heard it could be a stdin problem...

Comment: Did you actually open a console window ?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aYT8Ni

Comment: Might be a problem with the extension, do you have a C# extension installed in vscode?

Comment: i have the official C# extension and execute it with Code Runner

Comment: actually CS Script, Code Runner is reserved to c and c++

Comment: oh shift, it actually works on console

but still nothing on vscode

Comment: yeah seems there's something wrong with the vscode or the extensions. are they all updated?

Comment: any suggestion on what to do?

Comment: are they all updated? maybe try reinstalling vscode and the extensions.

Comment: if that doesn't work, also check for available windows os updates

Comment: ill try that, ty bro

Comment: consider posting your results here to close this question and help future readers with the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

###### Solutions

This problem is solved in two steps:

1. Adding [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019) to Visual Studio Code
2. Updating `"console"` field in the [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) file.

---

###### 1. Adding Developer Command Prompt to Visual Studio Code

If you create C# programs with the *terminal* or *powershell* that comes with Visual Studio Code, you will be using the old toolkit. In this case, *launch.json* and *tasks.json* files aren't created in the *.vscode* directory when you compile the project, and you cannot use the new features of the C# programming language through the old toolset (*only C# 5.0 is supported*). To add a new terminal to Visual Studio Code, use the <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> shortcut and enter the command `"Terminal: Select Default Profile"`. Click on the settings icon of any default terminal on the window that opens and name the new terminal profile *"Developer Command Prompt"*.

[image]

To check that the operation was successful, use the <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> shortcut to view the new terminal listed and enter the command `"Terminal: Select Default Profile"`.

[image]

Use the <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> shortcut and enter the `"Preferences: Open Setting (JSON)"` command to open the *setting.json* file. You can view the newly added terminal information named *"Developer Command Prompt"* under `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows"` settings. Update this field below:

```json
"Developer Command Prompt": {
   "path": [
      "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
      "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
   ],
   "args": [
      "/K",
      "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat",
   ],
   "icon": "terminal-cmd"
}
```

Open *"Developer Command Prompt"* and create new project:

```sh
> mkdir TestProject
> cd TestProject
> dotnet new console
```

To receive data input from the console while debugging, change the configuration in the *launch.json* file as follows:

```json
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

When you press the <kbd>F5</kbd> button to debug the opened project, a panel will open to select the environment. Select *".NET 5+ and .NET Core"* from this field. In this step, the *.vscode* directory ([launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) and [task.json](https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editor/tasks/) files) will be created.

[image]

Accept all suggestions by following the prompts at the bottom right of Visual Studio Code as the new toolset will be used for the first time on the system. At this stage, *launch.json* and *task.json* files will be created under the *.vscode* directory.

[image]

---

###### 2. Updating `"console"` Field In The *launch.json*

To receive data input from the console while debugging, change the configuration in the *launch.json* file as follows:

```json
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

---

###### 3. Debugging On Test Project

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug the project:

[image]

---

###### References

- [Visual Studio Code - Terminal Profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles)
- [OmniSharp - Instructions For Setting Up The .NET Core Debugger](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger.md)
- [Set As Default The Developer Command Prompt Of VS In VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986112/set-as-default-the-developer-command-prompt-of-vs-in-visual-studio-code)
- [Debug Console Window Cannot Accept Console.ReadLine() Input During Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195432/debug-console-window-cannot-accept-console-readline-input-during-debugging)